# Inconsistency in $z^{\omega} = \exp (\omega \log z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I recently encountered an inconsistency while using the formula for complex exponentiation $z^{\omega} = \exp (\omega \log z)$.

(1) If we set $z = 0 + 1i = i$ and $\omega = 1$ we obtain
$i = \exp (\log i)$.

(2) However, $\log i = \frac{i\pi}{2 \ln 10}$.

(3) Substituting the latter into $i = \exp (\log i)$ yields $i = \exp \left (\frac{i\pi}{2 \ln 10} \right)$.

(4) Having said that, since $\exp (i \pi) = -1$ we are left with $i = (-1)^{1/2} = (-1)^{\frac{1}{2 \ln 10}}$. But $1/2 \neq \frac{1}{2\ln 10}$.

Please explain the issue.

Comment: The complex logarithm is multivalued. And $i\pi/(2\ln 10)$ is not one of the values of $\log{i}$.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be thinking that $\log$ is the logarithm to base 10. In complex analysis (and many other post-calculus subjects), $\log$ denotes the natural (base $e$) logarithm. And to make things even more problematic, the complex logarithm, as you probably know, is not "single-valued".

If you want to talk about the base 10 logarithm, I'd recommend writing $\log_{10}$ (or possibly $\lg$), but never just $\log$.